# How to make Additional css changes global all across the web pages on WordPress website?

Tags: themes

So, I have my website on WordPress and I'm using Astra theme. I have implemented certain changes using Additional CSS, but the changes seem to have implemented over the homepage only and not on other pages so how do I make the similar changes all across the website?

This is my website https://www.decodedigitalmarket.com

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSS?

Comment: Styles added into Additional CSS are global styles that will be included on every page, if they are not working they may be using a selector that is targeting just the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what the selectors in Astra or elementor but, you'll have blocks of css like:

```
#post-423 > header > h1 {
    display: none;
}
```

If I wanted this specific rule to be sitewide I'd remove `#post-423 >` from that. If you provide us some of your custom CSS rules we could make a specific answer.